# Getting new unique purchase users from shopping table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a shopevent table which has transaction rows with column id, user_id, shop_date.
I can pull shop events with sometthing like

```
SELECT * FROM SHOP_EVENTS A LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_TABLE B ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID WHERE B.USER_REGISTRATION_DT BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
```

I also have a user table from which I can get users registered in a particular month.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE WHERE registration_date between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
```

What I am trying to achieve is how many new unique users made a purchase each month after they registered.

Here is the query I am trying.

```
SELECT
CASE
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-01-01'  AND '2012-01-31' THEN 1
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-02-01'    AND '2012-02-29' THEN 2
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-03-01'    AND '2012-03-31' THEN 3
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-04-01'    AND '2012-04-30' THEN 4
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-05-01'    AND '2012-05-31' THEN 5
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-06-01'    AND '2012-06-30 'THEN 6
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-07-01'    AND '2012-07-31 'THEN 7
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-08-01'    AND '2012-08-31 'THEN 8
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-09-01'    AND '2012-09-30 'THEN 9
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-10-01'    AND '2012-10-31 'THEN 10
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-11-01'    AND '2012-11-30 'THEN 11
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2012-12-01'    AND '2012-12-31 'THEN 12
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-01-01'    AND '2013-01-31 'THEN 13
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-02-01'    AND '2013-02-28 'THEN 14
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-03-01'    AND '2013-03-31 'THEN 15
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-04-01'    AND '2013-04-30 'THEN 16
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-05-01'    AND '2013-05-31 'THEN 17
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-06-01'    AND '2013-06-30 'THEN 18
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-07-01'    AND '2013-07-31 'THEN 19
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-08-01'    AND '2013-08-31 'THEN 20
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-09-01'    AND '2013-09-30 'THEN 21
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-10-01'    AND '2013-10-31 'THEN 22
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-11-01'    AND '2013-11-30 'THEN 23
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2013-12-01'    AND '2013-12-31 'THEN 24
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-01-01'    AND '2014-01-31 'THEN 25
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-02-01'    AND '2014-02-28 'THEN 26
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-03-01'    AND '2014-03-31 'THEN 27
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-04-01'    AND '2014-04-30 'THEN 28
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-05-01'    AND '2014-05-31 'THEN 29
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-06-01'    AND '2014-06-30 'THEN 30
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-07-01'    AND '2014-07-31 'THEN 31
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-08-01'    AND '2014-08-31' THEN 32
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-09-01'    AND '2014-09-30' THEN 33
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-10-01'    AND '2014-10-31' THEN 34
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-11-01'    AND '2014-11-30' THEN 35
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2014-12-01'    AND '2014-12-31' THEN 36
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2015-01-01'    AND '2015-01-31' THEN 37
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2015-02-01'    AND '2015-02-28' THEN 38
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2015-03-01'    AND '2015-03-31' THEN 39
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN     '2015-04-01'    AND '2015-04-30' THEN 40
 WHEN shop_date BETWEEN  '2015-05-01'  AND  '2015-05-31' THEN 41
END AS month,
count(user_id),
count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM
    shop_events a
inner join user_table b on a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE
    user_registration_dt between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
```

This is giving me unique users who made a purchase every month starting Month 1. How do I get a list of new unique users who made a purchase. This means, lets say out of 10,000 regitrations 100 users made a purchase in month 1. After that 50 new users who were not part of 100 from previous month made a purchase. How do I get new unique users in a query like this?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you *really* want is the first time that someone made a purchase.  For that purchase, they are unique.  (If I'm understanding your question correctly.)  You can calculate this using aggregation.

I'm not sure what output you want.  Nor do I understand what "one month" really means to you.  However, the following does the calculation by days:

```
select (shop_date - ut.user_registration_dt) as days_between, count(*)
from User_Table ut JOIN
     (select se.user_id, min(se.shop_date) as minsd
      from shop_events se
      group by se.user_id
     ) se
     on ut.user_id = se.user_id
where ut.user_registration_dt between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
group by days_between
order by days_between;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a "piece of the jigsaw": your lengthy `CASE` clause can be replaced by

```
MONTH(shop_date)+(YEAR(shop_date)-2012)*12
```

And *maybe* you wanted something like this:

```
-- lists for users of each registration month (uregmon) the shopping month no. (shopmon),
-- the total count of shopping events (shopcount) and the number of different customers 
-- in that month (custcount).
SELECT uregmon, shopmon, COUNT(suid) shopcount, COUNT(DISTINCT suid) custcount FROM 
( -- derived table: lists all user ids for each shop event in each numbered month
 SELECT MONTH(shop_date)+(YEAR(shop_date)-2012)*12 shopmon,USER_ID suid 
 FROM SHOP_EVENTS
) s JOIN
( -- derived table: lists user ids and the month no. of their registration
 SELECT USER_ID uuid,MONTH(registration_date)+(YEAR(registration_date)-2012)*12 uregmon 
 FROM USER_TABLE
) u ON uuid=suid
GROUP BY uregmon, shopmon
```

If you filter this table for a particular registration month (i.e. `WHERE uregmon=1`) you will get the same results as your original query.